# SQL select item from one table that is not in another

Tags: php, mysql, sql, codeigniter

I have a php page with a variable $lid, and a user with vairable $uid... I need to select some data from 2 tables to fill out the page.

```
        Table 1                          Table 2
¦----------¦----------¦    ¦----------¦----------¦----------¦
¦    qid   ¦    lid   ¦    ¦   owner  ¦   qid    ¦timestamp ¦
¦----------¦----------¦    ¦----------¦----------¦----------¦
```

I need to write an SQL statement that gets everything from table 2 where the owner = $uid if the qid is not already listed in table1 with the current pages' $lid.

I tried

```
SELECT * FROM table_two WHERE qid != (SELECT qid FROM table_one WHERE lid = " . $lid .") AND owner = " . $uid . ";
```

But had no joy

Any ideas?

Comment: If you're worried about performance, you will need to look at the query plans for the different queries proposed and/or measure the response times.  A lot may hinge on how many rows there are in Table_One that match rows in Table_Two.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This would work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_two 
WHERE qid not in (
    SELECT qid 
    FROM table_one 
    WHERE lid = " . $lid .")
```

This will probably perform better:

```
SELECT T2.* 
FROM table_two t2
LEFT OUTER JOIN table_one T1 ON T2.QID = T1.QID 
    AND T1.LID = " . $lid ."
WHERE T1.qid IS NULL
```

Answer (score 3):

You should use `LEFT JOIN` for best perofrmance:

```
SELECT a.*
FROM table_two a
    LEFT JOIN table_one b
        ON a.qid = b.qid AND
           b.lid = " . $lid ."
WHERE b.qid IS NULL;
```

See [Visual Explanation Of Joins](http://www.codinghorror.com/blog/2007/10/a-visual-explanation-of-sql-joins.html)

Comment: That is the most efficient query from the 4 answers. +1

Comment: no, is not. http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/04/22/sql-server-better-performance-left-join-or-not-in/

Comment: thanks! I think we are talking about MySQL server. I think that in most of the cases `LEFT JOIN` performs better than `sub-query`. Anyways it's always best practice to use `EXPLAIN` for every query.

Comment: you're right, mysql, sorry about that. In that case, they both run equally :P http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/

Comment: Hi... This query doesnt return the qid for some reason. Is there a way it can be edited to return that as well?

Comment: you should use `a.qid` column in `SELECT` clause as our `WHERE` condition is `'b.qid IS NULL'`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_two WHERE qid NOT IN (SELECT qid FROM table_one WHERE lid = " . $lid .")
```

Use `NOT IN` clause. This will give you the Id's that are not in your `subquery`.

**Edit**
You could also use `Left-Join`, In `MSSQL` is less efficcient, but this is `MySQL` (I didn't notice that), so they run equally. You can see it [here](http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/)

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM table_two WHERE qid not in 
    (SELECT qid FROM table_one WHERE lid = " . $lid .")
```

Answer (score 0):

You suggested to use:

```
SELECT * 
FROM table_two 
WHERE qid not in (
    SELECT qid 
    FROM table_one 
    WHERE lid = " . $lid .")
```

i also got same prblm but while im replaced wit "notin" it works fr me

Answer (score -1):

I would say use

```
SELECT * FROM table_two WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM table_one WHERE lid = " . $lid .")
```

Using the NOT EXISTS clause will give you a better query plan than NOT IN.

Comment: this probably wrong. Considering he is returning a different value that the one's using on the where

Comment: Also, considering it's good, is less efficcient that another 4 options http://explainextended.com/2009/09/18/not-in-vs-not-exists-vs-left-join-is-null-mysql/